# calculate multiple average from text python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to python, I wanted to get multiple average from a text file. for example:

- 63,  1,  1,  145,    233,    1,  2,  150,    0,  2.3,    3,  0,  6,  0
- 67,  1,  4,  160,    286,    0,  2,  108,    1,  1.5,    2,  3,  3,  2
- 67,  1,  4,  120,    229,    0,  2,  129,    1,  2.6,    2,  2,  7,  1
- 37,  1,  3,  130,    250,    0,  0,  187,    0,  3.5,    3,  0,  3,  0
- 41,  0,  2,  130,    204,    0,  2,  172,    0,  1.4,    1,  0,  3,  0
- 56,  1,  2,  120,    236,    0,  0,  178,    0,  0.8,    1,  0,  3,  0

  like I just want to get the average of certain columns like 1,4,5.

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.read_csv('HDPV.txt', "rb")
  columns = f.readline().strip().split(" ")
  numRows = 0
  sums = [0] * len(columns)
  for line in f:
  if not line.strip():
  continue
  values = line.split(" ")
  for i in xrange(len(values)):
      sums[i] += int(values[i])
      numRows += 1
      for index, summedRowValue in enumerate(sums):
          print ('average age:'columns[0],summedRowValue / numRows)
          print ('average chol:'columns[3],summedRowValue / numRows)
          print ('bp:'columns[4],summedRowValue / numRows)
  ```

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example?

Comment: something like : average age: 55  /n average chol: xxx /n bp: xxx im not sure if im using the comment right.

Comment: It seems like 'f' is undefined.

Comment: You are reading the file using Pandas.  Why not simply do `df.mean()` to get the average of each column?

Comment: if the first line of the file is a header just do `df = pd.read_csv('HDPV.txt', header=0)` then you can use `df.mean()` to get the average of all columns and pick out the ones you are interested in.

Comment: also you tagged this question with `python-3.x` but `xrange` is only in python-2.x...

Comment: ok, sorry I'm still new to forums, I've tried doing df.mean, but it wont work for some reason. so i use df.sum() / len().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use pandas, but this can be easily solve using python list comprehension:

```
import csv

with open('text.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    rows = [[value.strip() for value in row] for row in reader]

    average_age_list = [float(row[0]) for row in rows]
    print ('average age: ' + str(sum(average_age_list) / float(len(average_age_list))))

    average_chol_list = [float(row[3]) for row in rows]
    print ('average chol: ' + str(sum(average_chol_list) / float(len(average_chol_list))))

    bp_list = [float(row[4]) for row in rows]
    print ('average age: ' + str(sum(bp_list) / float(len(bp_list))))
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: thank you it works!!!!! i will work on the code more, because I want to learn  to use pandas better.